# remove/add class reload's improperly unless position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've created a very simple jquery slideshow, however I have an issue when a class is removed from the active image and placed on to the next one.

When the images position is **relative**: after the class is removed the new image briefly reloads underneath the slideshow

When the images position is **absolute**: The navigation of the slideshow become broken and it is no longer dynamic!

[Here is what it looks like when it's relative](http://storeco.de/)

[Here is what it looks like when it's absolute](http://storeco.de/bad.html)

How would i go about fixing this issue?

Comment: A quick note, you shouldn't use `li` directly inside a `div`. Some browsers will probably ignore it or display it wrong.

Comment: thanks for the note, I need to change that to an anchor tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the relative approach seams that the new image appears before the last one disappear completely, so the new image jump on container. I change the sliderResponse function to this:

```
function sliderResponse(target) {
  images.fadeOut(300).promise().done(function(){
  triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
  images.eq(target).fadeIn(300);          
  });
}
```

I used exactly the same code of http://storeco.de/, just changed the this function...

It's working on chrome, i didn't tested it in other browsers but you can try it.

That happened because you have:

```
images.fadeOut(300).eq(target).fadeIn(300);
triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
```

So, when you fadeout you just work with opacity, the content of image still there, when you fade in the newone it comes next and then the remove('selected') and addClass('selected') do the jump...
if you do this:

```
 images.fadeOut(300).removeClass('selected').eq(target).fadeIn(300);
 triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
```

It also works!

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS try changing (in the relative example)

```
.images li{
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     float:left;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

To

```
.images{
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     float:left;
     height:639px;
     overflow:hidden;
     z-index:100;
}
```

And

```
li {
        list-style:none;
}
```

should be

```
ul {
     list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: I wish this was the answer so badly, however if you define the height, then it won't be dynamic!

Comment: If you use `position:absolute` you can change the with with JS to center the `slideshow` http://jsfiddle.net/dAcnn/

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your javascript. Position relative is correct, but this is from your script:

```
function sliderResponse(target) {
        images.fadeOut(300).eq(target).fadeIn(300);
        triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
    }
```

This is setting both of the images to be visible for that 300 milliseconds with different opacities, pushing the second one underneath the top one as it disappears. I think this will fix it:

```
function sliderResponse(target) {
        images.fadeOut(300);
        setTimeout(images.eq(target).fadeIn(300), 300);
        triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
    }
```